# bootstrap navbar doesn't collapse with collapse class

Tags: html, css

I want that after I choose the option on the navbar, the navbar will disappear.
**How can I do it?**

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
    <img src="img/Tesler-256.png" alt="" width="200">
  </a>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/hq621m93/1/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/hq621m93/2/ ?

Comment: jsfiddle.net/hq621m93/1

Comment: Ok, it seemed like the layout might have been wrong. Might need to show more code in order to find the problem in your layout, or you could just rebuild it out with the jsfiddle I gave you. Best of luck.